# Create new site in sub-folder

Tags: site-directory

I will have a large number of meeting workspaces (>400) and want to create them in a subfolder to organize them separate from the other sites.  Keeping the URLs organized will help users with naming convention.  However, when I go to create the meeting workspace, I cannot add a folder in the URL i.e. http://site/meetings/meetingXX, where I am creating the workspace from http://site; it tells me that I cannot have a "/" in the [sub]-site I am creating for the meeting workspace.  Is there a workaround for this?  Also want to link this workspace in the calendar event, so if the solution is to do it through PS, will need a way to link this workspace back in the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this would be to create sub sites (not folders) for example of type "Blank site" to http://site.

If you use those sub sites to create meetings, you should be able to achieve something similar to your request

Comment: I would go with this route too, meeting workspaces are just bad implementations.  Going this route, you can create your own site template for the meeting workspace, and create the "meeting workspaces" from this.

Comment: Agree with PirateEric about the meeting workspace "template", I will have far too much commonality and customization to every "meeting" to not use a custom template.  With a blank site as a placeholder, how then do I link the event to the [sub-]site using the workspace field?  I assume that instead you have to manually put the link in the description?

Comment: you cant use custom templates (site definitions) with Meeting workspaces. It just doest work. Feature Stapling also doesnt work well, I experienced several occurances of racing conditions even though the features in the meeting site definition should have been finished before features stapled to the same scope would be triggered. And custom site definitions are not recognized in Outlook, as they have different IDs (also alot of code going on inside with hardcoded IDs as well). When i customize meeting workspaces i use custom provisioning providers or siteprovisioned event.