# SP 2010: Attach Recurring Calendar Event to a Meeting Workspace sitting in a SUBSITE

Tags: 2010, calendar, meeting-workspace, sharepoint-workspace

To better organize the work of several teams we need to have an additional subsite/folder inserted between the ROOT (this is where the shared calendar is available) and the WORKSPACES. There are several teams, but only one calendar which they need to share.
So basically:

**//site/** : This is the root site with the calendar that should be available to all teams

**//site/subsite1/** : This is the subsite to hold the name of the team

**//site/subsite1/workspace1/** : This is one of workspaces belonging to one of the teams which needs to be attached to the shared calendar.

By design SharePoint does not make this possible. While trying to connect a calendar event to a workspace there is only the option to type in a workspace' name which creates the workspace directly under the rootsite, with no option to add an additional subsite on the way.

This issue has been addressed in the following post, but the answer does not satisfy our need (we need to implement workspaces not blank sites:
[Create new site in sub-folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/create-new-site-in-sub-folder)